# Calling function from local scope without eval

Tags: javascript, closures

If you have something like that :

```
var ASK = (function (){
   var i = 0, _this = this;
   function private(){
      console.log(i++)
   }
   return {
      call : function (methodName, args){
         eval(methodName + '(' + args + ')' );
      }
   }
})();

ASK.call('private');
```

It's possible to call a function inside ASK scope without using eval ? And why when i try use `_this[method]()` I get that it's not a function ? Does `_this` shouldn't refer to scope inside `ASK = (function(){})`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use object:

```
var ASK = (function (){
   var i = 0, _this = this;
   var myFuncs = {
       private: function(){
          console.log(i++)
       }
   }
   return {
      call : function (methodName, args){
         myFuncs[methodName](args);
      }
   }
})();

ASK.call('private');
```

Comment: For completeness let me also clarify that `_this` isn't anything useful here, see my post

Comment: You don't have the `new` operator anywhere, what do you think `this` should be?

Comment: `new` totally isn't relevant for `this`, it's only needed for prototypes (and still not necessary since Object.create was introduced).

Comment: Yes... you are right. I mean at the point of `this` usage, there is no any new object. In the your code you have `{}`, which in fact is a synax sugar for the `new Object()`. http://ideone.com/kqpBT

Answer (score 0):

> Does _this shouldn't refer to scope inside ASK = (function(){})?

Nope. You aren't calling that anonymous function "through" any object which `this` could refer to, so `_this` ends up equal to `window` / `undefined` (depending on strict mode).

You're probably confused over how `this` works in JS. Please have a google on that for many good explanations.

Refer to **@kan**'s code snippet for how to solve this and note that closures actually solve the local variable scoping problem for you, so you don't really need to be concerned about `this` here.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/WCN5n/ 
http://jsfiddle.net/BkTDz/ 
http://jsfiddle.net/QgFfF/

Comment: Please add content as well as just links